# In WPF binding what does an empty {Binding} do

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In WPF binding what does an empty {Binding} do?
for example:

```
<TextBlock  Text='{Binding}' />
```

Is there an example where it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

It binds directly to the object in the current `DataContext` and is equivalent to

```
Text="{Binding Path=.}"
```

When the target property of the Binding is of type string (as e.g. the Text property of a TextBlock), built-in type conversion calls the object's ToString method (if it is not already a string).